# Customized DataGridView column does not accept the entered decimal seperator under Windows Vista

Tags: .net, datagridview, windows-vista, controls, numericupdown

For a project I built a custom DataGridView column which contains NumericUpDown controls. It is implemented similar to the suggestion from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(VS.80).aspx)

The column works fine under Windows XP. It accepts the entered digits and decimal separator.
Under Windows Vista I have the odd problem that the control only accepts the decimal separator entered by the numeric keypad but not from the keyboard main block.

I have to add that I work with German (Switzerland) culture settings under Windows Vista and the German (Switzerland) keyboard layout is activated. The decimal separator in Switzerland is .

Someone has an idea for the reason and maybe a solution? Thank you very much!

Michael

**Edit:** 
I found the solution to my problem.

1. To clarify the situation a little bit more. The NumericUpDown control I use implements IDataGridViewEditingControl and inherits from NumericUpDown. Because of IDataGridViewEditingControl I implement the method EditingControlWantsInputKey. And in the implementation of this method I found my mistake or what went wrong.
2. In the method I inspected the entered keys and decided if the control had to handle it. But for the decimal separator I only expected *Keys.Decimal*. In my special (wrong) case the key could not be matched. What was missing was to look for *Keys.OemPeriod* too. And that was the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please paste your OnKeyDown and/or OnKeyPress code? At least the relevant key-filtering code. It will make be easier to spot out any problems.

BTW, I normally use both a British English and Brazilian Portuguese keyboards, so I've had my share of these issues. That kind of forces you to become a localization expert :)

**Edit**: Oh, sorry, just re-read and understood you are using the stock NumericUpDown control. Can you point me out to the column code so I can try it here? Probably the locale is not getting set for the control, and you'll have to manually do it at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I found the responsible code and fixed it (see the edited part in the question).